# Advantage of client id and secret in oauth2 over regular username and password

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I am working on a backend system and we need to give our APIs to a third party. I am not really sure what authentication and authorization scheme to choose.

The current trend is the Oauth2 client Id and secret, but I don't understand what the difference between a username and password that returns a token for the third party and that protocol. In Oauth2, we need to provide the client ID and secret to the third party via secured channel. And then the third party can use them to have a token that lasts for certain period of time. Now, what is the difference between this schema or protocol and just providing username and password for the third party. If it comes to authorization, we can create a group table and assign each username to a group. I think it's just changing name from username to client Id and from password to client secret. What am I missing here?